# Evaluating complicated limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Edit: the original question was

> In an epidemic, there are at any particular time $x$ people not yet infected and $y$ people who are ill. The rate at which people become ill is $\alpha x$. The rates of recovery and death of those who are ill are $\beta y$ and $\gamma y$ respectively. If $x$ is initially equal to $N$ and $y$ is initially equal to zero, find an expression for the number of deaths up to time $t$ from the start of the epidemic. (Assume that those who recover are immune frmo further infection.)

I solved the differential equation to get this expression

$$\dfrac{\alpha \gamma N}{\beta + \gamma - \alpha} \Big[ \dfrac{1 - e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha} - \dfrac{1 - e^{-(\beta + \gamma) t}}{\beta + \gamma} \Big]$$

The question then asks to evaluate the limit as $\beta + \gamma \to \alpha$, and I'm having a bit of trouble with this. Clearly direct substitution fails. I know L'Hôpital's rule but am not entirely sure how I could apply this here, given the complicated expression and the fact that there are now multiple variables.

What might be the way to solve this, and is there any "smart" method that I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes behavior at infinity can be deduced from the original DE.  Please post it.

Comment: One idea that I would have would be to use a substitution. Replace $u=\beta + \gamma$. Then the expression inside the brackets approaches $0$, and the denominator of the expression left of the brackets approaches $0$, so you can apply L'Hopital's rule, deriving with respect to u.

Comment: I have included the question @B.Goddard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{ \beta+\gamma \to \alpha} y &= \lim_{\beta+\gamma \to \alpha}\dfrac{\alpha \gamma N}{\beta + \gamma - \alpha} \Big[ \dfrac{1 - e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha} - \dfrac{1 - e^{-(\beta + \gamma) t}}{\beta + \gamma} \Big] \\
&= \lim_{u \to \alpha}\dfrac{\alpha \gamma N}{u - \alpha} \Big[ \dfrac{1 - e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha} - \dfrac{1 - e^{-u t}}{u} \Big]  \\
&= \alpha \gamma N\lim_{u \to \alpha}\frac{\Big[ \dfrac{1 - e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha} - \dfrac{1 - e^{-u t}}{u} \Big]}{u - \alpha}  \to \frac{0}{0} \\
&\overset{L'H}{=} \alpha \gamma N \lim_{u\to \alpha} \frac{-\frac{u(-te^{-ut})-(1-e^{-ut})(1)}{u^2}}{1} \\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}

Hopefully this gives some insight.

Comment: I see it now, I did not think of combining the fractions in this manner. Thanks.

Comment: How about… $\gamma=u-\beta$ in the outer numerator? (I wonder because I genuinely don't know.)

Comment: @Rócherz I believe that is equivalent, so long as you do this for every instance of $\gamma$.